# Detect graphics driver information in Python

Tags: python, windows

I have an application the requires a minimum version of NVIDIA's graphics drivers installed to work. How can I get the driver version that is installed via Python on Windows?

EDIT:

A way to do this via the registry, which gives you all version installed (courtesy of Yojimbo)

```
cmd = r'reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\Stripped" /s | find "Display.Driver/"'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
all = [float(x) for x in re.findall('Display\.Driver/(\d+\.?\d*)', str(output))]
latest = max(all)
```

Comment: I've never saw this before, I'm curious to see the solution to this question, meanwhile have you found [this](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/300786/how-to-get-graphics-card-details-in-python)

Comment: You probably need to fetch the current version information from the registry, so a registry-parsing Python module would probably be a good starting point...

Comment: maybe a rough way to do it would be to issue command line commands from python? link [here](https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=23630) on how to print graphics version from command line...

Comment: @Yojimbo That turned out to be the easiest solution

Comment: For using the registry (e.g. Python's `winreg` module), normally you'd find this as the `DriverVersion` value in the key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{GUID}\0000`. But you need to find the active video device GUID, which will be the GUID with a subkey named `...\{GUID}\0000\VolatileSettings`.

Comment: That's is probably a much more elegant way than I posted in my edit. Finding what you want in the registry isn't always easy, thanks for the hints

Comment: Also look at the values `ReleaseVersion` and `BuildNumber` in the above key. Maybe one of those has the "347.9" number that you're looking for. Otherwise, short of calling an API directly, the installer information may be all you have, and that seems unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [wmi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) module, which requires PyWin32. Something like this, maybe:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

video =  c.Win32_videocontroller
print video.properties
```

I don't have a real Windows box at the moment and my Windows VM is returning a bunch of Nones, but I think this should work.

Comment: While I do believe this would work nicely, I do not want to install 1 or 2 extra modules just for the small need I have.

Comment: @steveo225, you can use wmic.exe instead. The most robust way to parse the result is using XML: `import os, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET;` `command = 'wmic path win32_videocontroller get /format:rawxml';` `tree = ET.parse(os.popen(command));` `result = tree.find('./RESULTS/CIM/INSTANCE');` `driver_version = result.find("PROPERTY/[@NAME='DriverVersion']/VALUE").text`.

Comment: @steveo225, here's the MSDN link for the [`Win32_VideoController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I do like that approach and it completes without error, however, it returns the wrong version. I get 9.18.13.4062 when my actual NVIDIA driver version is 347.9

Comment: @steveo225, do you see that number listed anywhere when you run the command interactively as `wmic path win32_videocontroller get /format:list`?

Comment: No, the version I expect is not there at all

Answer (score 0):

The WMI method mentioned above will give you the file version, not the actual driver version you expect. You need to install NVidia WMI and connect to root/CIMV@/NV namespace, where you can find System object with verDisplayDriver property that gives the driver version.

```
nvidia = wmi.WMI(computer, user=r"usern", password="pass", namespace="/root/cimv2/NV", find_classes=True)
for o in nvidia.System() :
    print o.verDisplayDriver.strValue
```